# Holomorphic functions in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose f is holomorphic in some region V of the complex plane and |$f^2(z)$-1|<1 in V. Prove that either Re $f(z)$ >0 or Re $f(z)$<0 throughout V. I tried to write $f(z)$as Re$f(z)$+i Im$f(z)$ and replaced in the inequality, but i did not know where i am going.

Comment: You have a good start!  Show your work so some people can assist you!

Answer (score 1):

$V$ must be a *connected* domain (otherwise the statement is not true).
$f$ is continuous, therefore $f(V)$ is connected as well.

$f(z)$ cannot be purely imaginary, as $|(iy)^2 - 1| = y^2 + 1 \ge 1$
for all $y \in \Bbb R$.

Therefore (with $H_+$ and $H_-$ denoting the right and left halfplane):
$$
 f(V) = \bigl( f(V) \cap H_+ \bigr) \cup \bigl( f(V) \cap H_- \bigr)
 =: V_1 \cup V_2
$$
is a representation of $f(V)$ as the union of two disjoint open sets.
Since $f(V)$ is connected, it follows that either $V_1$ or $V_2$ is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If the real part switches sign, then if you assume the region $V$ is path connected there is a point $z$ so that the real part of $f$ is zero (this follows from continuity).

At that point $f$ is pure imaginary and $f^2$ is a negative real number (or zero).

But then $f^2$ has the same sign as $-1$ and $|f^2-1|=|f^2|+1$ which cannot be strictly smaller than $1$.